# can i upgrade to 32gb ram?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have lenovo ideapad c340-15iml and my mother board is LNVNB161216 and it says that it only supports 16gb of ram but i want to upgrade it to 32gb.
i wonder if i could upgrade it to 32gb ram because if i check the max capacity in cmd it says that i could use up to 32gb.

**Ideapad:**

[image: c340-15iml]

**LNVNB161216:**

[image]

Comment: Depends. How many actual RAM slot is available there? If this manual is true - https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/c340_15_flex_15_hmm.pdf - it only shows 1 available RAM slot. Check the physical hardware using HWinfo - it can display how many RAM slots are being used (and the capacity of each). Chances are 1 is soldered in, and you can only replace the other one. So you might want to just open it up and physically check it first.

Comment: Theres only one slot that i can actually remove, the other one is 4gb ram and its soldered. The one that i can remove and change is the 16gb ram

Comment: Well... thats your answer (you answered it yourself).